# Using a closure table to get a hierarchical structure from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, menu, closures

I'm attempting to use a closure table to get the hierarchy from a table in MYSQL for a menu structure.

The main table is basically:

```
menu_id, title, parent_id
```

The closure table:

```
menu_id, ancestor_id, descendant_id, depth
```

Based on this, what is a basic way to:

1. extract the data in 1 query
2. process the data to output the hierarchy using php (the whole menu in this case).

Comment: i have not hear of a "closure table" at least in the mysql\php approach you seem to be using

Comment: I can advise a good book "SQL Antipatterns" by Bill Karwin. There is a chapter about the closure table with examples how to query it.

Comment: Could you explain the first question, what should be extracted exactly? By the way, do you know that this can be done using just one table :)

Comment: Thank you for the book reference.  Hex, you cannot do that in one table.  The closure table holds a one to many relationship.  The goal is to pull an entire n-level structure (or any level/child thereof) with one query with no recursion or other database calls.  The closure table grows exponentially when entries in the menu table are created, as each entry has all the ancestors, descendants, etc. available for the join.  This method allows you to know all the parents and children and peers from any element in the menu table.